# html input capture and upload failed iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html

I'm developing a webapp where the user able to upload some pictures from the device storage (mostly iphone). The upload is made using the html5 input file with capture attribute. but problem when try to capture from camera its not uploading.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

My problem is that if the upload will not have success the picture lost. Is there a way to store the picture in the device and upload it to the server?